# Show that f achieves either a minimum value or a maximum value.

Tags: general-topology

Let $f : R^2 → R$ be a continuous map such that $f^{−1}([−n,n])$ is compact for each positive integer $n$. Show that $f$ achieves either a minimum value or a maximum value.

I am not sure how to do this problem at all.  Not sure what to do with the proper map condition.  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pick any n.  as $f^{-1}([-n,n])$ is compact it it contained in a disk of radius $R_n$.  It follows that $|f| > n \forall |x| > R_n$.  However due to the connectedness of the exterior of the disk either $f > n$ or $ f < -n$.  Choosing n sufficiently large shows that a min or max must occur in $R_n$.